# Can someone please point out which induction's step I did wrong?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)(k+2)...(k+p-1)= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)} {p+1}$$

induction by substitute n+1:
$$(n+p+1)!= (n+p)!+(p+1)(n+p)! $$
I couldnt figure out how to countinue after this step. Thanks

Comment: If you want to decompose as a sum, it should be $\;(n+p+1)!=n\,(n+p)!+(p+1)\,(n+p)!$.

Comment: BTW, by dividing by $p!$, this is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k+p-1}{p} = \binom{n+p}{p+1}$.

Comment: No need of factorials. At the induction step you should show that
$$(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+p)= \frac{(n+1)\cdots(n+p)(n+1+p)} {p+1}-\frac{n(n+1)\cdots(n+p)} {p+1}.$$

Comment: @Bernard how did u get n(n+p)!  ?

Comment: I simply wrote $(n+p+1)!=(n+p+1)\,(n+p)!$, split the first factor in two and used distributivity, nothing more.

Comment: ah bless, thanks

Comment: @Bernard sorry I still didn't understand. I get how (n+p+1)!=(n+p+1)(n+p)!. But I still dont get the part how on the R.H.S, (n+p)! would render to n(n+p)! ?

Comment: This way: $(\color{red}n+\color{blue}{p+1})\,(n+p)!=\color{red}n\,(n+p)!+(\color{blue}{p+1})\,(n+p)!$. Each of the two terms that make up the factor on the left is multiplied by $(n+p)!$. Isn't that clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction step:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k+1)(k+2)...(k+p-1)=\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)(k+2)...(k+p-1)+(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+p)=\\
 \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)} {p+1}+(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+p)=\\
\frac{(n+1)(n+1+1)...(n+1+p-1)(n+1+p)} {p+1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have the answer for $n$.
For $n+1$, the sum will be $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k+1)...(k+p-1)$
That is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k(k+1)...(k+p-1) \ + (n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)$
Then, by induction hypothesis, you have $\frac{n(n+1)...(n+p)}{p+1}+(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)=\frac{n(n+1)...(n+p) + (n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)(p+1)}{p+1}=\frac{((n+1)(n+2)...(n+p))(n + p + 1)}{p+1}$
and you have your answer. Of course, you should also write down the basis for the induction.

Comment: I couldn't simplify it. The furthest I got is (n+p)!(p+1)+(n+p)!=(n+1+p)!, did I do sth wrong?

Comment: It's not that you've done something wrong. But I don't think you're getting anywhere with that approach. No need for factorials, try to use the induction hypothesis!

Answer (score 1):

The expression $$(n+p+1)!= (n+p)!+(p+1)(n+p)!$$

should have been $$(n+p+1)!= (n+p+1)(n+p)! =n(n+p)!+(p+1)(n+p)!$$

Comment: Can i ask how did u get n(n+p)!  ?

Comment: Distribute n+p+1=n+(p+1) over (n+p)!